# Why am I getting Azure Front Doors 400 error

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I have a static website set up using an Azure Storage account (blob storage). I want to use Azure Front Doors to handle url rewriting because it's an SPA and always needs to route to index.html in the back end. I've set up a Front Door using the designer. It has one front end (using a subdomain on the azurefd.net domain), one back end, which points to my back end blob storage account and has a matching host header, and one rule which is basically all defaults. I have it set to Match request for HTTP vs HTTPS.

How do you properly configure a Front Door for a static storage site in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 400 error can happen if you have not configured a routing rule for the frontend host. A routing rule needs to be **explicitly** added for that frontend host. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-troubleshoot-routing#hostname-not-routing-to-backend-and-returns-400-status-code).

You could get a deep understanding from [How Front Door matches requests to a routing rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-route-matching) and check if a valid request path in the routing rule matches the frontend host.

If there isn't a [custom forwarding path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-rewrite) defined, then the request gets forwarded to the appropriate backend in the configured backend pool as is. Else, the request path is updated as per the custom forwarding path defined and then forward to the backend. You could verify if the `forwarded path` is valid when you set the `custom forwarding path`.

[image]

If you have any question, please let me know.

### update

For configuring a Front Door for a static storage site in Azure. You could select a `custom origin` using the static website's URL instead of blob storage origin. Moreover, if you want the URL to be rewritten using a regular expression. You could use [Azure CDN for this static website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-custom-domain) instead of an azure front door. You could [override HTTP behavior using the Azure CDN rules engine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-rules-engine), so requires the use of the Azure CDN premium offering from Verizon.

More reference: [Serving Your Static Sites with Azure Blob and CDN](https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn/)

Comment: I did get it to work by not using the blob storage origin and setting it to use a custom origin and using the static website's url. But this was only a partial solution because I was getting an error with paths, most likely because I didn't set up all of the path patterns that I needed. I haven't had a chance to try again but I'll report back when I do.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I have Match Path: /* and Custom Forwarding Path: /index.html but when the Incoming URL Path is /about it errors our. I would expect ti the Forwarded Path to be /index.html.

Comment: After re-reading that article, the URL rewriting feature of Front Doors is not able to do what I want  it to.I want the URL to be rewritten using a regular expression. I don't want it to simply take the path matched by the wildcard and append it to the Forwarded path.

Comment: Yes, you should use the static website URl for the custom origin if this used for a static storage site since blob storage is different from website URI. If you did this blob storage, I think it should a 404 not found error instead of 400, I did not mention this at the beginning. Per your purpose, you could use CDN for this static website instead of azure front door. [refer1](https://blog.lifeishao.com/2017/05/24/serving-your-static-sites-with-azure-blob-and-cdn/), [refer2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-https-custom-domain-cdn#http-to-https-redirection)

Comment: Update my reply. If the reply is helpful, do you mind accepting it as an answer for more people reference?：）

Comment: Thanks Nancy. I accepted your answer even though I have tried Azure CDN. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the URL rewriting to work correctly with assets (js, css, images) so I ended up implementing it with 3 Azure Function Proxies. This allowed to rewrite the url easily.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Function Proxy is also another good option.

Comment: @VictorP we are trying to accomplish that same thing you were - have the URL rewrite 
 create a custom forward path by actually REPLACING part of the incoming path, not just appending it.  It's been a year since this thread was active - any idea if this functionality has improved over the last year.  The documentation for this feature seems to indicate we can do what we are trying to do - but all I get is 404 errors, indicating the URL rewrite clearly isn't working correctly.

Comment: @Stpete111 I ended up using AWS CloudFront as my CDN. Got it set up in less than a day with an AWS Lambda to do the rewriting. I could never get FrontDoors to work and I didn't want to use Azure API Management due to the pricing.

Comment: Correction, API Management was for a different use case, not for the static site.

Comment: @VictorP thanks for the confirmation!  So then you were easily able to point AWS CloudFront to your Azure resources I take it?

Comment: @Stpete111 yes there was no special setup involved. You can use the AWS guide to set it up.

Comment: @VictorP it looks like AWS CloudFront max connection timeout is 60 seconds.  Front Door is 4 minutes and we need at least that amount.  Are you able to confirm I'm reading correctly that the max send/receive timeout on AWS is only 60 seconds?  Sorry to keep bringing this up in this thread - there is no direct message capability on S/O as you know.

Comment: @Stpete111 yes, it appears you are correct about 60s being the max. But you may be able to have an AWS tech increase the limit for you. I've had them change limits on things before. Can't hurt to ask.